# What is the "meta" for declaring binary numbers in Java?

Tags: java, binary

I'm just wondering why everyone declares binary numbers like this:

```
int val1 = 0b1010;
int val2 = 0b10000001;
```

when this declaring a number like this `float val1 = 0b1010;` works as well.

I'm working on a project that deals with image pixel color values, so I need to manipulate the saturation level of each color value (by reading them off the image) into a float between `0.0` and `1.0`. I'm assuming declaring each initial binary as an integer has something to do with ease of manipulation when masking and such, but I haven't seen any particular rule of thumb other than every example that I've seen initializing the variables as an `int`.

(For my use an example would be:

```
double val = 0b100000; //this is equivalent to 32.0
System.out.println(test1/255.0); //this gives out the ratio, namely 0.12549...
```

In this case I would skip the need to cast anything...)

Thank you for taking the time to clear this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare `float val1 = 0b1010;`, that is the equivalent of declaring `float val1 = (float)0b1010;` The cast from `int` to `float` is implicit, but it is still performed.

Comment: Awesome! So there's nothing wrong with directly initializing the variable as a float I'm assuming...

Comment: @AndresStadelmann There's nothing "wrong" with it, as in it will still compile. However, it's not doing exactly what you think it's doing. In your second example, for instance, the double representation of 32 is 01000010000000000000000000000000, not 0b100000, so a casting operation is taking place. That operation is just done without the programmer having to specifically request it.